# Getting PySide2 QTabWidget to look more like Maya’s native version

Tags: pyqt, pyside, maya

anyone know how to get rid of the thin line under all the tabs in a QTabWidget so it can be more like a maya native bit of UI? I tried a stylesheet of ("QTabWidget::pane {border: 0px solid #000000;}") which does remove it but breaks more things for some reason, making the unselected tabs as light as the selected tabs, no idea why, guess my stylesheet experience is failing me. (uncomment the style sheer line in the code below) thanks

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
        
class Tab1(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None, ):
        super(Tab1, self).__init__(parent)
        
        main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        main_layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("Tab:"))
        main_layout.addStretch()

        
class TabWidgetTesting(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TabWidgetTesting, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setMinimumSize(240, 320)

        self.create_widgets()
        self.create_layouts()
    
    def create_widgets(self):
        self.Tab1 = Tab1()
        self.Tab2 = Tab1()
        
        self.tab_widget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        #self.tab_widget.setStyleSheet("QTabWidget::pane {border: 0px solid #000000;}") 
        self.tab_widget.addTab(Tab1(), "Tab 1")
        self.tab_widget.addTab(Tab1(), "Tab 2")
        
        
    def create_layouts(self):
        main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.tab_widget)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_dialog = TabWidgetTesting()
    test_dialog.show()
```

I expected Maya's internal styliing to handle this and for them to look the same as a native one without the little line underneath

edit: Added images:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ddf14.png)

Comment: The documentation [explains](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1) that "With complex widgets [...] if one property or sub-control is customized, all the other properties or sub-controls must be customized as well": if you only set one property, all remaining aspects will revert to basic primitives. I don't really know how Maya draws tabwidgets (an image would greatly help), but it's possible that they use custom widgets/drawing for some of their controls, meaning that the only way to "copy" that behavior would be to do it too.

Comment: Maya doesn’t use stylesheets, it uses QStyle.  QStyle + stylesheets don’t mix. So if you set a stylesheet on a widget, it overrides a bunch of other values that you didn’t explicitly set in the stylesheet. That’s why it looks bad when you set the stylesheet.

There is no way to extract an equivalent stylesheet from Maya.

Could try QProxyStyle., you would have to subclass it and override some methods to change how the QTabWidget pane is drawn. Then you wrap the current style in that proxy, and set that proxy style on your dialog. I think it is the “Technically Correct™” way to do this.

Comment: "QStyle + stylesheets don’t mix" That's actually wrong. Qt **always** uses QStyle, when using style sheets then it changes the current style to a special QStyleSheetStyle (which inherits from the basic QWindowsStyle) and eventually reverts to the current base style as proxy. Also, `QWidget.setStyle()` has effect **exclusively** on the widget it has been called upon, not any of its children (existing or future). Since you see a different look for tab widgets, then the possibility is that Maya uses custom QTabWidget/QTabBar classes that are drawn differently either with specific style sheets »

Comment: » with selector types, that they have a custom proxy style that behaves differently when it detects their specialized classes (or that their parent window is a Maya window), or they just override painting. In the first case, it may be possible to inspect the Maya window, look for their tab widgets and see if they can be identified in some way. In any case, as said, having an image that shows the tab widgets may actually help us understand the differences.

Comment: apologies, I've added an image to the post, this one https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ddf14.png